# Get a list of all custom post type names/slugs

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a dropdown-list of all my custom post types.

It would look like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="post">Post</option>
  <option value="book">Book</option>
  <option value="some-other-post-type">Something</option>
  <option value="team">Team Members</option>
</select>
```

I have come across the `get_post_types()` function which is supposed to get a list of all registered post type objects. But it doesn't show my custom post types...

Is it possible to get an array with the slug and the title of all the post types registered in a theme? Considering the number of post types is unknown and dynamic. Every time a new custom post type is added or removed, it should reflect in the dropdown list.

My test:

```
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false // Use false to return only custom post types
);

$post_types = get_post_types( $args );

print_r($post_types);
```

It returns an empty array... no custom post types that I registered.

Comment: How do you use that function? Show your current code, pls.

Comment: Just `get_post_types()` and it returns an object but no custom post types included.

Comment: But where do you use it? How do you use it?

Comment: I used it in functions.php. I am just testing it to see what it returns. I'm trying to find a starting point to build the actual function. i'm not sure where to start to get the post type names

Comment: it all depends on context... Seriously, show us your code, or we won’t be able to help you... It’s hard to guess what’s wrong with code that we can’t see...

Comment: There;s no code. Thats what I need help with. Not asking for an entire function, just some guidance on where i can start. All I found is `get_post_types()` but is not what i need

Comment: So start exactly there - ‘get_post_type’ is the function you should use. There is no other correct way to get list of post types.

Comment: `get_post_type()` retrieves the post type of the current post. It's totally irrelevant to what I am trying to achieve. Have you actually read the question? I'm trying to generate a list with the names of custom post types. Not sure how much clearer it can be....

Comment: get_post_types() - sorry for typo. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż ok I have added some code to my question. What I did with `get_post_types()`

Comment: Ok, so for the last time I’ll ask... where and how do you run that code - the context is very important, because you can’t obtain list of post types too early... You’re really making it very hard to help you...

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry I was not understanding. I was just dropping it into functions.php outside any other function/wrapper. Now I have added it in `add_action('wp_loaded', function(){` and it is working. The new challenge however will be getting the name of the post types that i used as label when registering them

Comment: what exactly do you mean? What do you want to get?

Comment: Well, I was thinking for the HTML select options to get the post type label name that I passed when registering the post type.I mean this `'name'                  => _x( 'Books', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),` but not sure if that's even possible

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż if you want to post the answer with` get_post_types()` I will mark it correct. Forget the getting names. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the function [`get_post_types`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) is exactly what you're looking for.

```
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
   '_builtin' => false
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {

   echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
}
```

But there are few things you should be careful about:

- You can't get these post types too soon. It's very common practice to register the post types on `init` hook, so you won't get these post types before that hook is fired up.
- If you'll query for public post types, you'll get only the post types that are registered as public (and not that are public based on other args)...
- By default this function will return you only names of post types. If you want to obtain more info, you can pass `objects` as second param.